# Why is jQuery ajax returning a bogus error callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I visit a page that contains a button which makes a jQuery ajax `$.post` call for the first time, upon clicking on the button the expected URL is successfully hit and the action sends back the expected `JsonResult`. HOWEVER, the `$.post` immediately hits the error callback function before the action even runs (remember though, the action method DOES run, the result is simply not being awaited) and the error messages returned are null or empty strings. In other words, it should have hit the success callback but it hits the error callback instead. Hmmmm.

Here is the resultant alert statement:

> ":  Server error. Could not vacate the locker. Try again."

If I hit the button a second time, again, the expected URL is (also still) hit, but this time the `$.post` (correctly) waits for the response before making the decision on whether to run the success or the error callback, and it (`$.post`) correctly calls the success call back function.

Here is the resultant alert statement:

> "Locker C18 has been successfully vacated and unassigned."

Why is it doing this?

JavaScript/jQuery

```js
$.post({
    url: '@Url.Action("ReclaimAlocker", "Ajax")',
    data: {
        lockerId: id
    },
    success: function () {
        alert('Locker ' + lockerNumber + ' has been successfully vacated and unassigned.');
        location.reload();
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {
        alert(a.responseText + ' : ' + c + ' Server error. Could not vacate the locker. Try again.');
    }
});
```

MVC Action (in a controller called AjaxController)

```c#
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReclaimAlocker(long lockerId)
{
    var lockerAssignments = _amsDb.LockerAssignments.Where(k => k.Active && k.LockerId == lockerId).ToList();
    foreach (var assignment in lockerAssignments)
    {
        assignment.Active = false;
        assignment.DateRemoved = DateTime.Now;
        _amsDb.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    var locker = _amsDb.Lockers.Find(lockerId);
    if (locker != null)
    {
        locker.Occupied = false;
        _amsDb.Entry(locker).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    _amsDb.SaveChanges();

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is the info from the Network tab of Chrome Dev tools:

```
Name                Status      Type      Initiator       Size  Time
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1st attempt
ReclaimAlocker      (canceled)  xhr       jquery.min.js:4  0 B  37ms
LockerAssignments   200         document  Other           7.7KB 32ms

All subsequent attempts
ReclaimAlocker      200         xhr       jquery.min.js:4 7.7KB 39ms
```

Comment: can you include the rendered jquery (without the razor tag) and where the variable `id` is declared and assigned.

Comment: As you mentioned you are getting an error, can you post the response text?

Comment: @Steve -- I believe the id is irrelevant ... it successfully makes it to the controller.

Comment: Can you use the developer tool to check what URL is being hit 1st click and console for the error.

Comment: @Karthik -- as I mentioned, there is the error messages are null ... there is no error code nor any error message ... it is bogus, doesn't exist. But the rest of the text in the error comment is returned. That being said, to reiterate that fact, I'll post the response.

Comment: try removing  "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" as this is a post request

Comment: @Devesh -- the url hit both times is the same /Ajax/ReclaimAlocker

Comment: @Karthik -- I tried that and it doesn't help if it is removed. I get the same behavior if I make this a $.get, $.post, or $.ajax.

Comment: That first time, in the network monitor of your developer tools,  what response is it actioning.  (is it cached?)

Comment: Does the first request show as a 200 in the network tab?

Comment: @Steve and nurdyguy --  your questions may be driving towards an answer if you have ideas from my answer. I have placed the Network info in the edited post.

Comment: The `(canceled)` makes me think it's posting back your form and not using the ajax call. The immediate 200 for the parent page(?) LockAssignments seems to confirm that. You may need to add prevent the default action in your button click handler.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan ... adding preventDefault() to the click handler does not help. Doing so still drops straight to the alert message that is sent from the ajax error handler. But worse, it also prevents the method from running. You said 'not using the ajax call'. For clarification, the method that ajax is calling to runs every time, regardless of the success or the error callback. That's why this is such a conundrum. The error callback fires even though the call to the method was a success.

Comment: Why are you even using ajax? On success you're reloading the page anyway, so doing a post back makes more sense. In any case, it's impossible to tell what's going on, since you haven't shown the relevant code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: lincstar182 please provide at the very least additional code/context around the ajax call.  It will be difficult to proceed further without additional information, consider posting a minimal/complete/ verifiable example as suggested by @Mike